# How to put a like box/button on a Dreamweaver MX v6.0 designed site?

Tags: facebook, dreamweaver, facebook-like

Basically i'd like to put a like button on the website so that fans of the site can like the websites Facebook page.

The Like button page doesn't give me the code when i click the button, just says "Only verified developers can be added as listed developers of this application. Read www.facebook.com/help/?faq=17580 for details." Is this a common error, or?

***EDIT: Using Like box now, but would prefer Like button.** 
And the like box page gives me the iframe and XFBML codes. Sorry for being a n00b, but how do i add either one onto my site? I've tried Insert > Script and pasted it in there, using all four script types (Javascript, JS 1.1, JS 1.2 and VBScript but they don't show in the preview. Placed the code under the 'back to top' button at the bottom of the page. Not showing up when i look at code view of the online version though?
Hopefully its something really easy and obvious, but any help would be great.
Again, site is designed/updated with Dreamweaver MX 6.0.*

Comment: Promoting your project site like that looks very close to being spammy from where I'm sat. You can ask this question perfectly well without having to mention your site.

Comment: I didn't need to put the Facebook page link there no, but i had the site link there so people could take a look at the source code to maybe help me out better as to why the Like button hasn't shown up. Its just a test page and may not look exactly like that when the whole site is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have that much experience with Dreamweaver - but implementing the facebook social plugins (eg. Like button) is very simple.  All you have to do is copy and paste the XFMBL you generate from [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).  Once you paste your URL into the "URL to Like" field and click "get code" you should get the correct code to use...
You place this code wherever you want it to appear - if you want the like button to be in the footer just paste it there... 
The code snippet actually loads the facebook javascript sdk and places your like button inside an iframe on your page...
You can not place the like button code inside a different element - if that were possible people could trick you into liking their page by writing some different label on the button - eg. "Back to top" :)

This should be relatively simple to implement. If you are still having dificulties - why not try opening a new HTML file containing only the required HTML tags and the like button code...

Hope this helps! 
Good luck!

Comment: Cheers. Got the Like box showing, but still get that message when trying to get the Like button. Ah well.

Answer (score 0):

The error appears because, just like it says in the message, you are not a verified developer.
In order to be a verified Facebook developer, you need a verified Facebook account, with a credit card or a phone number verification.

I'd suggest you verify your account as soon as you can if you plan to use more of Facebook's plugins and apps, since it will give you full access to their developer tools

Comment: Its a bit confusing in a way (to me), as it seems like a 'Facebook Developer' is someone who creates stuff for Facebook (apps etc) and thus is unrelated to wanting code for the like button to go on websites.

Don't have a credit card, and not getting a text back for the verification even thgouh i've tried it two or three times now.

Comment: A developer account gives you access to more features and stats about your website, the number of likes and, depending on your settings, which like button generated the more clicks and so on. It's weird the text verification didn't work, it went smoothly for me and I don't even live in the US. Maybe you should try contacting their help center